# Run script or java batch is usb device is connected to raspberry pi

Tags: shell, usb, raspberry-pi, execute

I'm trying to run an shell script, if a special usb device is connected to my raspberry pi. I have tried to follow following description:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-502864.html

I created a file named 85-my_rule.rules with the content:
ACTION=="add",SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device",SYSFS{idVendor}=="ffff",SYSFS{idProduct}=="1000",RUN+="/usr/bin/usbdevinserted"

My script usbdevinserted has the following content:
echo "Dies ist ein Text" >>/tmp/text

If I execute this script on the shell, the text file named text ist created with the content "Dies ist ein Text", so the script works fine. But it seems not to be executed, if I connect an usb device to the rasppi. So I think, the error is in my rule, but I cannot found it. Can anyone help me please?

Greetings,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Are the vendor and product ID correct?

ffff and 1000 looks weird but it may be possible (e.g some eval board).

Usually, "dmesg" prints out VID/PID (plug/unplug a couple of times, "dmesg", check the last lines)

Also, double-check whether it's a hex-decimal conversion problem (try decimal 65535 and 4096)

Comment: Hi, yes i think these values are correct. I executed lsusb (as described) and got 4 lines displayed. Then I connect my usb device (a digital picture frame) and execute lsusb again. And the only changed line is the line with these values.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. I had to change my rule to the following rule:

```
ACTION=="add",SUBSYSTEM=="block",KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*",RUN+="/usr/bin/usbdevinserted"
```

and my script is now:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Dies ist ein Text" >>/tmp/text
```

but I do not know why I had to insert the first line in my script. Can anybody explain this line please?

Greetings,
Andreas